# Different behaviour when defined as a function and when computed as a variable

Tags: haskell

sorry for the title, I could not think of a better one.
I wanted to show the fact that in a group of 23 people it's more likely that there are two with the same birthday than not when I wrote this function:

```
birth :: Int -> Double
birth n = (fromIntegral . product $ [365,364..366-n]) / (fromIntegral . product . replicate n $ 365)
```

which does not work properly while these three do

```
birth1 n = (fromIntegral . product $ [365,364..366-n])  / (fromIntegral $ 365^n)
birth2 n = (fromIntegral . product $ [365,364..366-n])  / (fromIntegral . product . replicate 23 $ 365)
birth3 n = (fromIntegral . product $ [365,364..366-23]) / (fromIntegral . product . replicate n $ 365)
```

The results:

```
birth  23 == -1.7444829681771515e-41
birth1 23 == 0.4927027656760146
birth2 23 == 0.4927027656760146
birth3 23 == 0.4927027656760146
```

The most surprising is that the first one is negative. Why is this behaviour? I renamed everything and tried again before posting this, nothing is imported except for `Prelude`.

Cheers

Comment: @bheklilr I initially though the same, but the type of `birth3` also seems to be of Int: `birth3 :: Fractional a => Int -> a`

Comment: You certainly need to use `Integer` though.  `product . replicate 23 $ 365 == 85651679353150321236814267844395152689354622364044189453125`.

Comment: And `birth3` can also be `Int -> Double` because `n` is only used for `replicate`, not for setting the bounds of the product in the numerator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by an overflow....

Consider just part of the numerator alone

```
> product [366-(22::Int)..365]
4190530200557060096

> product [366-(23::Int)..365]
-1494178958273413120
```

Once you get past a certain point, the value goes negative....  This is because int only goes to 2^64 (one bit is used for the sign, so going to 2^63 will cause things to go negative).

```
> 2^63-1::Int
9223372036854775807

> 2^63::Int
-9223372036854775808
```

The `Int` type is actually cyclical, tied to the size of values on your system.  Once you cross this magical value, the values cycle back through large negative numbers....

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of integer overflow, I was just surprised that these seemed to be semantically equivalent and had no idea why there was the difference. I should mark this as an answer because this was first, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're using `Int` instead of `Integer`.  If you change the definition of `birth` to be:

```
-- Helper function
(//) :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> a -> b
x // y = fromIntegral x / fromIntegral y

birth :: Integer -> Double
birth n = product [365,364..366-n] // (product . replicate (fromIntegral n) $ 365)
```

You'll get the right answer.

You unfortunately can't use an `Integer` for the first argument of `replicate`, so you have to convert it to an `Int`.  You could alternatively use `birth :: Int -> Double` and `product [365,364..366 - fromIntegral n] // ...`, which would probably be safer.

---

As for your other definitions, `birth1` could easily have the type `Integer -> Double`, as could `birth2` because the `n` is only used in the numerator, while in `birth3` you get away with `Int -> Double` because `n` is only used as the argument to `replicate`.  In fact, if you type these definitions directly into GHCi, you see that the types of these functions are

```
birth :: Fractional a => Int -> b
birth1 :: (Fractional a, Integral b) => b -> a
birth2 :: (Fractional a, Integral b) => b -> a
birth3 :: Fractional a => Int -> a
```

So it's only `birth` and `birth3` that restrict you to using `Int`, but because of the way you defined `birth3`, you still get the right answer.

---

Another way to do this with only `Int` is to perform the divisions as you go, then do the product.  This keeps you from having to convert very large numbers, but it might be slower depending on `n`.  You could do this as

```
birth :: Int -> Double
birth n = product $ take n $ zipWith (//) [365,364..] $ repeat 365
```

Which is arguably easier to read as well (I like it better, but that's just an opinion).